# Anti virus interfering with auto-updater for C# application

Tags: c#, .net

I've been trying to create an updater app for my .NET application that gets called when an update is detected using a text file that includes the version info. I've created the said updater but it has some problems. When the file is downloaded, it seems like the anti virus software corrupts the file and it can't be opened. Sometimes the updater doesn't run at all and throws an exception ("The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.") which seems to also be caused by the local anti virus software. I figured maybe I could download the file in binary format and create the executable locally, but I am not completely sure on how I would do that (or if it would even work). I am still very much a beginner in a lot of areas. So my question is.. how can I efficiently download an update for my application without triggering the anti- virus?

My code:

```
public Updater()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DownloadInfo.RemoteURI = "http://mywebserver.com/Application.exe";
        DownloadInfo.NewExecutableName = "update.exe";
        DownloadInfo.ExecutableName = "Application.exe";
        DownloadInfo.LocDest = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        InvokeUpdate();
    }

    private void InvokeUpdate()
    {
        Thread thr = new Thread(() => GetUpdate());
        thr.Start();
    }

    private void GetUpdate()
    {
        Process[] proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("Application");
        if (proc.Length != 0)
            proc[0].Kill();
        Util.DownloadFile(new Uri(DownloadInfo.RemoteURI), DownloadInfo.LocDest + DownloadInfo.NewExecutableName);
        if (File.Exists(DownloadInfo.LocDest + DownloadInfo.ExecutableName))
            File.Replace(DownloadInfo.LocDest + DownloadInfo.NewExecutableName, DownloadInfo.LocDest + DownloadInfo.ExecutableName, DownloadInfo.LocDest + "backup.exe");
        else
            File.Move(DownloadInfo.LocDest + DownloadInfo.NewExecutableName, DownloadInfo.LocDest + DownloadInfo.ExecutableName);
        try
        {
            File.Delete(DownloadInfo.LocDest + "backup.exe");
        }
        catch { }
        try
        {
            Process.Start(DownloadInfo.LocDest + DownloadInfo.ExecutableName);
        }
        catch { };
        Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => this.Close()));
    }
```

And my DownloadFile method from my util class..

```
public static void DownloadFile(Uri remoteURI, string localDest)
    {
        try
        {
            using (WebClient webclient = new WebClient())
            {
                webclient.DownloadFile(remoteURI, localDest);
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried adding your app in the Exception list of the given anti-virus?

Comment: Yes when the anti virus is disabled, everything works as its supposed to and the application updates. But my hope is that users can install the updates without having to go out of their way and disable the anti- virus software.

Comment: I've used an auto updater library before that downloaded the update just fine. But the files were stored on the server in binary format, which is what leads me to wonder if that might be the answer. But I feel like the anti virus software would take similar action as soon as the file is created.

Comment: Where is your updater located and is it run as admin?